$R$ ring such that for all $a \in R$, there exists $b \in R$ such that $a^2b=a$

Let $R$ be a ring such that for all $a \in R$, there exists $x_a \in R$ such that $a^2x_a=a$

Show that $ax_a=x_aa$.


The condition $a^2x_a=a$ implies that $R$ is reduced as if $a \neq 0$ were nilpotent and $m=\min\{k \in \mathbb{Z^{+}} \mid a^k=0 \}$,
$$a^m=0 \underbrace{\implies}_{m \geq 2} a^{m-2}a^2x_a=0 \implies a^{m-1}=0; $$
which contradicts the minimality of $m$.
This implies the $\textit{Von Neumann}$ regular ring's condition as:
\begin{align*}
&(ax_aa-a)^2=ax_aa^2x_aa-a^2x_aa-ax_aa^2+a^2=ax_aa^2-a^2-ax_aa^2+a^2=0 \\[7 pt]
\therefore \; & ax_aa=a
\end{align*}
Expanding $(ax_a-x_aa)^2$:
$$(ax_a-x_aa)^2=ax_a-ax_a^2a-x_aa+x_aa=ax_a-ax_a^2a$$
But I couldn't find any useful relation that'd unable me to conclude that $ax_a=ax_a^2x_a$; any suggestions?
